# Read Metadata from multiple files (namely Images with Copyright info)

Tags: images, batch, file-management, metadata, exiftool

I'm attempting to produce a report of metadata from images within a network drive and all of its subfolders to check copyright information and other metadata (Creators, Authors etc). Recursively and vast quantities (10's of thousands). I'm not too worried about editing/changing, just reading and reporting.

I've seen many tools for editing and viewing metadata, but i'm after an application/utility which will search for files, then produce a report of what it finds (ie not changing anything).

> Scenario: Salesmen have a vast directory of images used for
>   promotion, labels and uploading to web. Someone previously saved an
>   image for a product from the web, this makes it onto promotional
>   material online. The original author identifies the image by it's
>   metadata and makes an illegal useage complaint.

I'm attempting to use [EXIFTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to do this and finding there's far too many arguments for me to easily figure it out from the commandline.

My current attempt looked like this - "`exiftool.exe -r -COPYRIGHT -URL -RIGHTS -AUTHORS -COMPANY -CREATORS  M:\Images\* >> C:\location\list.txt`" Which is 80% there as it appears to not be recursive (even with the -r) and ideally i'd want to strip the files without meta content from my results...

I've read through most of the posts in [metadata](/questions/tagged/metadata) and will continue to work with EXIFTool until i get some results (will post info back here) but i'm interested to hear of others tools and peoples experiences with metadata.

*Any information regarding the legality of using such files in the UK also greatly appreciated!*

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 32bit, but will happily use anything to produce my list/report!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rediculuously simple as it sounds - simply run exiftool WITHOUT the list.txt option, and see if that outouts everything you want. If it does, simply direct it with > to a text file.

If putting them into one folder isn't an option i believe you can append to list.txt with >>.

In short, counterintuitively, don't use the 'proper' way, and use an ugly hack with standard text streaming methods

Comment: `exiftool.exe -r -COPYRIGHT -URL -RIGHTS -AUTHORS -COMPANY -CREATORS  M:\Images\* >> C:\location\list.txt` is working for me but doesn't appear to be recursive...

Comment: I've done what i wanted with **`exiftool.exe -csv -r M:\Images\* -FILENAME -COPYRIGHT -URL -AUTHORS -COMPANY -CREATORS -CAMERA >> C:\location\list.csv`** will mark this as the answer as it helped me get there! :)